# cross_Validation in oneR usuing R language

Tags: r, syntax-error, cross-validation, training-data, caret

I'm trying to cross-value with the OneR algorithm and I don't quite know how to do it.With the example code I get the error "Error in x[0, , drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions"

```
glass <- read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/glass/glass.data",
                  col.names=c("","RI","Na","Mg","Al","Si","K","Ca","Ba","Fe","Type")

str(glass)

head(glass)

standard.features <- scale(glass[,2:10])

data <- cbind(standard.features,glass[11])

data$Type<-factor(data$Type)

anyNA(data)

inTraining <- createDataPartition(data$Type, p = .7, list = FALSE, times =1 )

training <- data[ inTraining,]

testing  <- data[-inTraining,]

set.seed(12345)

fitControl <- trainControl(## 5-fold CV
  method = "cv",
  number = 5
  
)

model <- OneR(Type~.,data= training)


oneRFit1 <- train(model, 
                 trControl = fitControl)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly easy to write your own loop to carry out cross-validation. However, it looks like you want to use the `caret` package to manage it. If so, just use the `method` argument inside `caret`'s `train` function to specify that you want to use OneR:

```
oneRFit1 <- train(Type~., 
                  data=training,
                  method="OneR" ,
                  trControl = fitControl)
```

Comment: Applying your suggestion I get the following error: predictions failed for fold1: parameter = none Error in predict.OneR(modelFit, newdata): cannot find feature column in newdata.

Comment: I ran your code from the beginning, just replaced the final bit, and it works for me. I don't get the error you mentioned. Have you tried running from scratch, to make sure you haven't accidentally made changes to the data? Are you sure you pasted my code exactly, and ran it straight after you defined fitControl?

Comment: Yes, I have applied the changes and it continues to give me the same error.

Comment: I don't know what to say - I tried again, it works fine for me if I follow your code up to and including defining the fitControl, and then use my code. Are you sure you are also specifying the model in the `train` function now? e.g. including `Type~., data=training`. As opposed to trying to do this separately using the `OneR()` function as you do in your example.

Comment: This is the code I am using

Comment: To make it easier I have changed the data and reduced lines of code.

Comment: str(iris)
head(iris)
set.seed(123)
inTraining <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p = .7, list = FALSE, times =1 )
training <- iris[ inTraining,]
testing  <- iris[-inTraining,]
set.seed(123)

train.control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 2)
# Train the model
oneRFit <- train(Species ~., data = training, method = "OneR",
trControl = train.control)

Comment: This is being caused by a package conflict between `caret` and `OneR`. Try re-starting your R session, and only load the `caret` package before running the code.

Comment: I finally got it to work. I have eliminated some library that loaded at the beginning. Problem solved. Thank you very much for the support and follow-up. I removed OnneR library

Comment: No problem, please accept answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

str(iris)
head(iris)

```
set.seed(123)
inTraining <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p = .7, list = FALSE, times =1 )
training <- iris[ inTraining,]
testing  <- iris[-inTraining,]
set.seed(123)

train.control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 2)
# Train the model
oneRFit <- train(Species ~., data = training, method = "OneR",
trControl = train.control)
```